# Unable to login through social login in AEM 6.2

Tags: facebook, authentication, aem

I have configured social login in AEM as given in https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/communities/social-login.html. I'm using Geometrix-outdoor component to login. The page is http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html [on top right corner we have login].

All the configurations are good. When I click login, the pop up for facebook login comes (OAuth login succeeds). When the call back happens, the OAuth Handler is not able to find the class **com/day/cq/personalization/ProfileUtil** in 6.2. In 6.1 this functionality works fine.

**Below is the log:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/day/cq/personalization/ProfileUtil
    at com.adobe.cq.social.connect.oauth.impl.FacebookProviderImpl.getCurrentUser(FacebookProviderImpl.java:368)**
    at com.adobe.granite.auth.oauth.impl.servlet.OAuthProfileImportServlet.updateUserDataAndRedirect(OAuthProfileImportServlet.java:130)
    at com.adobe.granite.auth.oauth.impl.servlet.OAuthProfileImportServlet.requestAccessToken(OAuthProfileImportServlet.java:115)
    at com.adobe.granite.auth.oauth.impl.servlet.OAuthProfileImportServlet.doGet(OAuthProfileImportServlet.java:82)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:269)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:140)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:345)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:376)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:546)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)

It is helpful to identify the root cause and rectify. Thank you

Comment: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/diff-previous/changes/pkg_com.day.cq.personalization.html - The class is removed from the API. So What is the other way to use this facebook login functionality

Answer (score 0):

In AEM 6.2, com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.profile.ProfileUtil is deprecated. Please 
Use com.day.cq.personalization.ProfileUtil instead.

Answer (score 0):

Social login cannot be used on author nodes. It is only valid on publish nodes because it creates community users. Community users do not exist on author nodes.

I wish the error message were more clear...

Comment: But I'm able to use AEM 6.1. what is the difference made between 6.1 and 6.2?

Comment: The FacebookProviderImpl.getCurrentUser() method uses different codepaths depending on whether the AEM is an author instance or a publish instance. The codepath for a publish node does not use the com/day/cq/personalization/ProfileUtil class. In 6.1 that class was available but in 6.2 it is not. In 6.1 users were replicated, so publish users existed in author. In 6.2 users are now moved between publish nodes by using Sling Content Distribution, and never exist on author.